# How to save a WebView state in fragments when changing the orientation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I have a webview, I need to save the state of that webview when changing the orientation. I want to load the different layout when changing the orientation, but am using fragment. How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 6):

Implement this on your fagment that contains the WebView:

```
private Bundle webViewBundle;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    setRetainInstance(true);
    ...
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
    wv = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    if (webViewBundle != null)
    {
        wv.restoreState(webViewBundle);
    }
    else
    {
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.mysite.mydomain");
    }

    return v;
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webViewBundle = new Bundle();
    wv.saveState(webViewBundle);
}
```

And add this in your Manifest `<activity>` tag:

```
 <activity
        ...
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        ... ></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

private WebView wv;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_layout, container, false);
    wv = v.findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wv.loadUrl("http://example.com/");

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation in plain English for your answer to improve its quality and describe how your code solves the OP's problem. Please also remember to format the code correctly before answering.